# How to Redirect this URL to my home page In HTACCESS file

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, redirect

I am new with PHP , 
I want to redirect this URL to my home page www.laroute-angkor.com by Edit HTACCESS file

Here the url that i want to redirect when the visitor click or visit :

```
www.laroute-angkor.com/component/k2/item/68-tours-by-sub-categories/68-tours-by-sub-categories?cat_id=23&start=5710
http://www.laroute-angkor.com/component/k2/item/62-bakheng-mountain/62-bakheng-mountain?start=1222270
http://www.laroute-angkor.com/component/k2/item/497-tours-by-sub-categories?cat_id=38
http://www.laroute-angkor.com/component/k2/item/496-tours-by-sub-categories?cat_id=38
```

Comment: @PlantTheIdea http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/15660/148364 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63255/148364

Comment: @Prix i was unaware of these discussions, and i knew that i was being somewhat rude with my response. not nearly as rude as wasting resources and time with such a simple and obvious question that someone can discover the answer to in seconds, but rude nonetheless. in the future i shall just vote to close and leave a comment about how the most minimal form of investigation is necessary before you demand help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below will redirect all the 4 links above mentioned to your index page.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cat_id=23&start=5710$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/68-tours-by-sub-categories/68-tours-by-sub-categories/?$ /? [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^start=1222270$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/62-bakheng-mountain/62-bakheng-mountain/?$ /? [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cat_id=38$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/49(6|7)-tours-by-sub-categories/?$ /? [R=301,NC,L]
```

NOTE: If what comes after the ? is not important just it it like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/68-tours-by-sub-categories/68-tours-by-sub-categories/?$ /? [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/62-bakheng-mountain/62-bakheng-mountain/?$ /? [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/49(6|7)-tours-by-sub-categories/?$ /? [R=301,NC,L]
```

The difference between the 2 is that the second will redirect:

```
http://www.laroute-angkor.com/component/k2/item/68-tours-by-sub-categories/68-tours-by-sub-categories?cat_id=23&start=5710
```

Even if it have something else after the `?` so basically it can be anything after `?` and it will redirect while the first set of rules will redirect only if what comes after `?` is exactly `cat_id=23&start=5710` on the same order.

Comment: I can't Vote up , it require reputation 15 , But can click accept this answer

Comment: @MsyMarina thanks, you don't need to vote up, just accepting it as the right answer is enough.